# passing dropdownlist value to another page asp.net using postbackurl

Tags: asp.net

There are other questions with similar titles, but nothing I can find fixes my issue.

I have a form on page1 with a Dropdownlist and a button. On the button I have a postbackurl specified. I need to retrieve the value of that dropdownlist from page 1, on page 2. I have omitted the codebehind for page 1 and the aspx for page 2 since they are irrelevant. Can you help me solve my problem?

ASPX Page 1

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCountryList" runat="server" CssClass="ddlstyle" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="if(this.selectedIndex == 0)return false;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Country_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Country" Value="Country" Selected="True" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="USA" Value="USA" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Canada" Value="Canada" />
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Register" CssClass="pink-btn" PostBackUrl="/page2"/>

</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind for Page 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Testing
{
    public partial class WebForm11 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string DDLCountryList = Request.Form["DDLCountryList"];


        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DDLCountryList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Querystring

Comment: That is not a very helpful response. I don't want to use querystring.

Comment: That's why I put as comments. Thanks for clarifying that you don't want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Master Pages. They rename the ID of the control to something like `MainContentPlaceHolder1_DDLCountryList`. This also happens with the `name` of the Control. That will become something like `ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder1$DDLCountryList`.

Now when you capture a Form Post you need the `name` as the key, not the `ID`. So you are using the ID of the Control that does not even exist while you should be using the aspnet-renamed name.

So try this on the page with the DropDownList on it to get the correct key.

```
string DDLCountryList = Request.Form[DDLCountryList.UniqueID];
```

That is the key value you need to capture the form post on the other page.